Inconsistent HTML conversion using showdown npm when transforming Markdown to HTML and back—how can I preserve indentation structure?
HTML content:
<p>This is a heading</p>
<ul><li><p>This is a bullet point</p><ul><li>
<p>This is a sub bullet point</p>
</li></ul></li></ul>

Converted markdown content:
 'This is a heading\n' +
     '\n' +
     '* This is a bullet point\n' +
     '   * This is a sub bullet point'

Converted content from markdown back to HTML:
\n' +
   'This is a bullet point\n' +
   'This is a sub bullet point\n' +
'
My Question:

Why is the conversion back to HTML from Markdown resulting in inconsistent formatting?
How can I preserve the original bullet point structure when converting between HTML and Markdown?
Are there any libraries or methods that handle this conversion more reliably?

Any guidance on how to maintain a consistent structure through these conversions would be greatly appreciated!

AFAIK, showdown (like most markdown converters) considers source code formatting (like indentation) information not worth preserving. it's simply not a use-case most markdon converters support, because few people need it. why do you think you need that?

Thank you for your input! In our project, preserving the exact formatting, especially indentation, is crucial from a user perspective. We are working on a feature where users rely on structured content like bullet points, and maintaining their original formatting ensures clarity and readability. So, having the Markdown converter handle this is important for us to meet our users' needs effectively.

I cannot think of any markdown converter that does something like that off the top of my head. Why not store the markdown string separately in your database or wherever?
